# Is the (deterministic) monotone assumption for an instrumental variable in conflict with the positivity assumption for potential outcomes?

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables

Is the (deterministic) monotone assumption for an instrumental variable in conflict with the positivity assumption for potential outcomes?

Z is the instrument, X is the treatment, Y is the outcome and all 3 are binary

Assuming Z meets all conditions to be an instrumental variable, except for the heterogeniety condition, then the (deterministic) monotone condition says that we can divide the population into 4 types

1. compliers (always have X=1 when Z=1 and always have X=0 when Z=0)
2. defiers   (always have X=0 when Z=1 and always have X=1 when Z=0)
3. always takers (always have X=1 regardless of the value of Z)
4. never takers (always have X=0 regardless of the value of Z)
   and either there are no compliers OR there are no defiers

But *if we want to use the potential outcomes framework* aren't the always takers and never takers already excluded from the population by the positivity restriction? Since for every subject, the probability that X=1 can not be 0 or 1

Comment: the positiity assumption is across the population, not "for every subject"

Comment: I agree if that was the way positivity was consistently defined, but it is not. From a Rubin paper (for example) "Probability is 'probabolistic' if  each unit has a positive probability of  receiving either treatment". And "each unit" sure sounds to me like it is defined at the subject level.

Comment: i don't think that's right - it's not clear what the probability is over when looking at a single unit. the unit either receives the treatment or not. If possible, please provide a reference that states the assumption mathematically (rather than in text).

Comment: This is a problem with the PO framework. Exactly how the probability is defined is  unclear. Define B (baseline covariates), Y(0), Y(1) potential outcomes and these are vectors (for entire population or sample, not really clearly defined), then papers frequently define as 0<P(X_i|B,Y(0),Y(1))<1.  The problem is whether or not this is a probability conditional on subject i or not is not clearly defined. And it matters. And if one is attempting to glean which definition, the language in the papers "unit-level probability" implies the former".

Comment: Also, yes *after* the study is conducted each subject either receives treatment or not, so conditional on the study the only way X_i can be a random variable is unconditional on subject i. But the PO framework *starts* with a population where treatment assignment is random. Leads to even more confusion as there are a few different ways to define X_i as a random variable.